# Encrypting with GPG using PHP exec

Tags: php, encryption, exec, gnupg

I try use php exec function to encrypt an given string like

```
exec("echo test | /usr/local/bin/gpg -e -a -r name@host.local --trust-model always", $output, $encrypted);
echo $encrypted;
```

That same command works fine in command line and outputs the encrypted message. But for whatever reason I get always 2 as exit code when running in PHP. I figured out that it could be a permission problem. But how to solve it? I read about setting --homedir but without success :(

BIG thanks in advance!

PS: I cannot simply use the gnupg php module…

Comment: Does GPG output some error message, probably to stderr? According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50541/what-does-gpg-error-code-2gpg-err-unknown-packet-mean the exit code 2 is a generic "unexpected condition" error. Regarding permission errors: under which user do you run the php interpreter? Is it the same one you tried out the command in the command line? If not, try that and check if you get the same errors.

Comment: Which user runs the web server (and thus `gpg` here), does it have a home directory where GnuPG can create its configuration directory? If using `--homedir`, does the web server has appropriate permissions?

Comment: Try to read (cat) a common file to test access conditions instead of running a full gpg command where anything can go wrong; try and narrow the problem down.

Comment: I can do a simple cat on a file with exec. And I also switched to the whomai user and executed it in command line which worked also. Any ideas?